# HttpSession.invalidate don't work - cant logout a user in my application

Tags: java, spring, session

I have issue in program, i try to logout user using method invalidate from HttpSession, but attribute user still exist. Session still contains attribute "user" and index mapping redirect user to /user. invalidate() should delete all atributes from session, but it is not happend, why?

Logout mapping

```
package revo.first.site.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
import revo.first.site.mechanics.Authentiaction;
import revo.first.site.repositories.Repository;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SessionAttributes({"user","message"})
@Controller
public class AuthController {

    //Data

    @Autowired
    private Authentiaction authentiaction;
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    //Register form

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model, @RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password, @RequestParam String email){
        if(!authentiaction.register(login,password,email)){
            model.addAttribute("message", "Nie udalo sie zarejestrowac!");
            return "redirect:/register";
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", repository.getUserRepository().findByLogin(login));
        return "redirect:/user";
    }

    //Login form

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, @RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String password){
        if(!authentiaction.login(login, password)){
            model.addAttribute("message", "Nie udalo sie zalogowac!");
            return "redirect:/";
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", repository.getUserRepository().findByLogin(login));
        return "redirect:/user";
    }

    //Logout user
    @RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(HttpSession session){
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

Views mapping

```
package revo.first.site.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttribute;
import revo.first.site.SiteApplication;
import revo.first.site.entities.User;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Controller
public class ViewsController {

    //Show index.html

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model,@SessionAttribute(name = "user", required = false) User u, @SessionAttribute(name = "message", required = false) String msg, HttpSession session){
        this.addAttributes(model);
        if(u != null) {
            u.toString();
            return "redirect:/user";
        }
        if(msg != null && msg != "") model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        else model.addAttribute("msg", "");
        session.removeAttribute("message");
        return "index";
    }

    //Show register.html

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model, @SessionAttribute(name = "message", required = false) String msg, HttpSession session){
        this.addAttributes(model);
        if(msg != null && msg != "") model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        else model.addAttribute("msg", "");
        session.removeAttribute("message");
        return "register";
    }

    //Show user.html

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model, @SessionAttribute("user") User u){
        this.addAttributes(model);
        model.addAttribute("u", u);
        return "user";
    }

    //Add App atributes to model

    private void addAttributes(Model model){
        //Add atributes
        model.addAttribute("title", SiteApplication.APP_TITLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpSession is just an interface. Implementation depends on servlet containter. Try to invalidate session two times on logout. If it will trow IllegalStateException  on second call then it should be working.

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String logout(HttpSession session){
    session.invalidate();
    session.invalidate();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Comment: I do it, but it didn't help, session was invalidate first time.

Comment: There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
invalidate: Session already invalidated

Comment: But after invalidate, User still exist, invalidate don't delete him

Comment: I try to use removeAttribute("user"), but didnt work too

Comment: Okay, i solve it, i need to delete user from model. model.asMap().remove("user"); fix it :D